# How to connect FB page-app ID with a user profile link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

To summarize the issue shortly, I am making a web-app which allows users to register on my website and manage their social media profiles from there. This is not intended for private users, but rather for business pages.

Now let's say John owns a hotel.
John registers himself at my web-app, connects his facebook, twitter and whatnot to it and makes some post about a discount price for the summer.
Bill sees the post on facebook page (since he is an avid follower of John's hotel) and comments on it. Bill also sees John's tweet and being a creep that he is, comments there as well.

In my app, all the people that register have a "customer list". This list represents people that interact with any of their social media pages, this list is easy to populate, however, Bill on twitter and Bill on facebook, whist being one person in reality, have no connection on this list. Since John's facebook page-app ID for Bill is 123456, whilst twitter's is 7890112,  and since API doesn't give us any unique identifier such as an email or a profile link, rather only the name and an ID, how would I "connect" the two Bills?

**Also, mind you, it is not an issue of cross-social media connecting...**

Lets say I can force bill to come to my website and leave me a link of his facebook profile, *`facebook.com/profile/billTheCreep`*. I still cannot connect this profile to john's facebook page-app related id for Bill (123456) because that number and the name "Bill" is the only info a facebook page gives me. Forget for a moment the whole cross-social media issue, how does one take the app and connect the page-app unique id to a real user, not just an arbitrary name?

Is there even a way?

Comment: without explicit confirmation of the user, there is no way to link two different platforms/accounts.

Comment: Its not about different platforms, lets just say facebook alone, I cannot get the email, the profile link, nothing really that would let me "store" info in my own database, even if i have this user's links/mails, i still cannot tell the page to get ID for certain profile

Comment: of course not, why would any user want you to store any data of him without his explicit permission? that would be a major privacy issue. or why would anyone want his facebook account be connected with some already existing profile without his permission? and even if that would be ok, you are right about not being able to connect his profile with a page scoped id. unless maybe with the business mapping api, but of course the user has to authorize your app for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Comment: There used to be a possibility to get a `link` for a user profile, which would be enough to connect them, however this is gone now. As I said i can get the 'explicit premission' its all about the bonuses the user would get for registering. The idea here is user gives his own facebook profile link to my web-app, from this point on, any business page that he comments on, can identify HIM by his profile, rather then the page-specific user ID. I can still use the user id within a page, but need to be able to connect the user across pages. There needs to be a possibility for a "user feed"

Comment: did you take a look at the business mapping api?

Comment: No I have not, i will look into it